# Какие cистемы предотвращения вторжений существуют для ubuntu?

Tags: безопасность, linux, ubuntu

Какие cистемы предотвращения вторжений существуют для ubuntu, а то через iptables не реально всё предусмотреть? Snort как мне известно только извещает, но не блокирует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В десктопной версии предпочитаю скрипт Arno-iptables-firewall: http://unixteam.ru/content/obzor-arno-iptables-firewall-nastroyka-faervola-cherez-skript-arno-iptablesКстати, юзать его я начал именно со времён ADSL, и потом он так и остался.

Answer (score 3):

fail2ban - анализ логов и бан тех, кто попал под шаблон

Comment: не особо пригодился

Answer (score 2):

Как бы не показалось Вам странным, самая простая и надежная защита от вторжений это:

1. правильно настроенный firewall
2. политика ограничений
3. регулярные обновления безопасности

Iptables сложный. Для множества задач достаточно обойтись UFW:

**UFW**: https://wiki.404.city/ufw

Посмотрите текущие соединения. Разрешите необходимое и заблокируйте ufw все остальное. Поставьте необходимые права на файлы, запускайте сомнительные программы в песочнице. Настройте регулярные обновления.

Помимо firewall  другие популярные системы предотвращение вторжений, это SELinux и AppArmor. SELinux и AppArmor эффективны, но требуют большого времени для настройки (при использовании на декстопе).

**SELlinux:** ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux

**AppArmor**: ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor

Answer (score 1):

Snort и подобные ей системы предотвращения вторжения предназначены скорее для защиты сетей, а не отдельных хостов, и уж точно не для защиты десктопа. Это не аналоги продуктов вроде Kaspersky Internet Security (: Это немного про другое.

На сколько я понимаю вы хотите защитить свою рабочую станцию от посягательств из сети. В случае с большинством дистрибутивов GNU/Linux для этого достаточно «не стрелять себе в ногу». К сожалению способов выстрелить себе в ногу существует великое множество и невозможно предостеречь ото-всех.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на проект  [SmoothSec | Intrusion detection made simple.](http://www.smoothsec.org)

[Представлен SmoothSec 3.2, дистрибутив для быстрого развёртывания IDS/IPS](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=37749)

Comment: там же просто предустановленые компоненты snort

Comment: snort там как один из компонентов.

Answer (score 0):

1. Настройте Firewall и задайте его зону для новых сетей по умолчанию.
2. Переключите SELinux в режим "enforcing" и тип защиты в "mls". Настройте ограничения для процессов. Используйте SELinux.
3. Настройте и используйте auditd для аудита файловой системы.
4. Настройте и используйте fail2ban/sshguard для ограничения количества попыток неавторизованого доступа.
5. Используйте best-practice при настройке демонов.
6. ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ SELINUX!